# How do I build a beta app using Ruby on Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise-invitable

I am building a Rails app, but I want to build a beta version first, to understand how the users will use the platform.

In my home page, it'll have an email input and a button for interested users submit their email.

So I need to store this email in the database. I was considering create a table named "Interested_users" (or something like that), just to store the users email.

And with that data, I'll send an invite for specific users using "devise_invitable" gem.

Is this approach right? Does exist a better solution?

Thanks in advance, guys.

**EDIT:**
What I tried to say was: I already have my application in Rails. But I'm trying to do a closed beta, just for a few users. I'm not trying to build a landing page with Rails. It's really overkill. I want just to closed for a few users.

Comment: You could use something like [landing.js](https://github.com/vah7id/Landing.js), this might intereset you.

Comment: landing.js require PHP in the server. I'm using Rails 4

Comment: My mistake, I did not notice that. Well you could just use the plugin concept to build your own.

Answer (score 1):

All you need is a html landing page with a mailing list subscribe form (like mailchimp), and perhaps some social media links.

Building a rails app for your landing page seems a overkill.

Comment: Hey, I edit my question. I think I couldn't explain what I want for my application. Please, see my edited question.